# BLOCK_TYPE_VALID error when calling delete [] on pointer to object

Tags: c++, oop, memory-management, dynamic

This Code returns an error on the delete [] placard_; call

```
void Protestor::destroy() { //Free's caller Protestor's dynamic memory
    delete [] placard_;
}
```

This code does not.

```
void Protestor::destroy() { //Free's caller Protestor's dynamic memory
    delete placard_;
}
```

This goes against my class notes, which state to ALWAYS call

```
delete []
```

rather than

```
delete
```

What is the explanation for this behaviour? Under what conditions must 'delete' be called instead of 'delete []'?

Here is the Definition for the Protester and Sign classes.

```
class Protester
{
  public:
    Protester(string name, string signSlogan, int signHeight, int signWidth,
              int rcmp_file = 0 );
    string getName() const;
    Sign getPlacard() const;
    void changePlacard( string newSlogan, int newHeight, int newWidth);
    void setRCMPfile(int RCMP_file);
    int getRCMPfile() const;

    //Big Three
    Protester(const Protester& other); //Copy Constructor
    ~Protester(); //Destructor
    Protester& operator= (const Protester& other); //Assignment Constructor


private:
    // name of the Protester
    string name_;

    // a sign the protester is wielding
    Sign* placard_;

    // the RCMP file number tracking this person (zero means no RCMP report)
    int rcmp_file_;

    //Big Three Helper Functions
    void copy(const Protester& other); //Performs Deep Copy of const Protester&
    void destroy(); //deletes [] placard_
                    //sounds better then cleanup, in my humblest of opinions.
};

class Sign
// a class representing information about signs/placards
{
public:
    // constructor to initialize sign text and dimensions
    Sign(string statement, int height, int width);

    // return sign text
    string getStatement() const;

    //return sign height
    int getHeight() const;

    //return sign width
    int getWidth() const;

    // change sign text
    void setStatement(string statement);

    // change sign dimensions
    void setSize(int height, int width);

private:
    // the text of the sign
    string statement_;

    // dimensions of the sign
    int height_;
    int width_;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This goes against my class notes, which state to ALWAYS call delete [] rather than  delete

No that's wrong. You have to pair calls to `new` and `delete` and calls to `new[]` and `delete[]`.

**Note:**
But that's not how you should to that in modern C++. Use `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` instead. This is usually a much safer choice. Calls to `new/new[]` should be nearly always enclosed in smart pointer and `delete` should not be needed at all. Very few exceptions.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that the std::shared/unique_ptr approach is under the umbrella of RIiA? I have been reading much about it outside of class, but I'm afraid my TA's probably don't want to have to sift through any code outside of the lab scope.

Comment: They are linked yes. If you can't use them because of your lab restriction, then don't. It is usual on SO to mention what is the ideal way of doing.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `new Object()` you should use `delete`

When you use `new Object[]` (and array of objects) you should use `delete[]`

Answer (score 1):

`delete[]` is called to free a dynamically allocated array: `new type[]`

`delete` is called to free a dynamically allocated object: `new type`

See [delete C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_%28C%2B%2B%29) Wikipedia page.

Note, that if the `destroy()` function is invoked twice an attempt will be made to free an already `delete`d object as `placard_` is not `NULL`ed after the `delete` (if `delete` is called on a `NULL` pointer it has no effect).

Comment: I was told by my professor that delete[] would still work on individual objects. Does that only apply to standard types?  EDIT: I believe I misread his intention. His example was a little convoluted, I see the distinction now.

Answer (score 0):

You use operator delete[] only when you're allocating with operator new[]. Furthermore, you should try to use containers (vector, list, ..) and smart pointers (unique_ptr, shared_ptr).